# Adding a string to every column in a line- excluding the first column, variable line length, the string is contained in the first column of each line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file with multiple lines/rows, and each line contains a variable amount of columns:

```
Name1 String111 String112
Name2 String121 String122 String123
Name3 String131 String132 String133 String134
```

And so on and so forth (no pattern as to what line has how many entries).
I would like to add the name in the first column to the beginning of every column in that line/row such that I end up with:

```
Name1 Name1String111 Name1String112
Name2 Name2String121 Name2String122 Name2String123
Name3 Name3String131 Name3String132 Name3String133 Name3String134
```

We can start it simple and get more complicated:

How to add a string such as "Test" to the beginning of every column?

How to add the value in column 1 to every column in that row, including column 1?

How to add the value in column 1 to every column in that row, not including column 1?

My best guesses:

I do not know how to call "every column" and I do not know how to make the command access the currently column so I can only add a string or the value in column 1 to a single other column:

```
awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '{ !$1 = "hello" $2}' 
awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '{ !$1 = $1 $2}'
```

Is there a good resource on where I can learn this syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just iterate over all fields starting with the second, and concatenate the first field to whatever you already have:

```
$ awk '{ for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ $i = $1$i }}1' file
Name1 Name1String111 Name1String112
Name2 Name2String121 Name2String122 Name2String123
Name3 Name3String131 Name3String132 Name3String133 Name3String134
```

The `1` in the end is awk shorthand for "print the current line". You could write the same thing like this:

```
$ awk '{ for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ $i = $1$i }; print}' file
Name1 Name1String111 Name1String112
Name2 Name2String121 Name2String122 Name2String123
Name3 Name3String131 Name3String132 Name3String133 Name3String134
```

The basic idea above can be trivially expanded to match all of your examples. `NF` is the special awk variable that holds the number of fields; it will always be set to however many fields are present in the current line. Then, `awk` allows you to refer to specific fields using a variable. So if you set `i=5`, then `$i` is equivalent to `$5`. This then lets you iterate over all fields using the `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) { }` format which sets `i` to all numbers from `2` to the number of fields on this line.

Answer (score 4):

If your first field can't contain `&` then all you need is:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"&"$1)}1' file
Name1 Name1String111 Name1String112
Name2 Name2String121 Name2String122 Name2String123
Name3 Name3String131 Name3String132 Name3String133 Name3String134
```

Answer (score 2):

In any *awk*:

```
awk '{ OFS=" "$1; $1=$1 }1' infile
```

this sets OFS to *`<SPC><first-column's-value>`* then re-evaluate the fields based on the OFS by `$1=$1` then print (see [*awk idiom 1*](/q/63891/72456)).

can be written also as following

```
awk '{ OFS=" "$1 } $1=$1' infile
```

... but then that would fail for the lines that first field is `0`; here we can use empty string `""` to force *awk* for string assignment, so the result of `$1=$1""` would always evaluate true and so result of assignment would be true then default print action will be triggered for those lines as well:

```
awk '{ OFS=" "$1 } $1=$1""' infile
```